# Pyomo Setting bounds of indexed variables differently

Tags: python, modeling, pyomo

I am trying to create an indexed variable in pyomo, but I want to sets the bounds of the various indexes differently like this:

```
model.vProduct = Var(SC, N, G, bounds=(0, limit[g])
```

Where SC, N and G are ranges so it has 3 indexes.
(Which dos not work because like this I am assigning a vector of upper bounds to each variable)

Now I want it to be like `model.vProduct[SC, N, 0] bounds are (0, limit[0])` etc.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a rule (a.k.a. a Python function) to the bounds keyword to do this

```
def _bounds_rule(m, sc, n, g):
    return (0, limit[g])
model.vProduct = Var(SC, N, G, bounds=_bounds_rule)
```